# Diffrence between LO Tx and LO Rx of two B10 even connected to Octoclock

Tags: usrp

I have two B210 connected trough splitter.
They both use external Octoclock REF and PPS.

I have:
|complex sine| -- |uhd sink| -- |b210| -- |splitter| -- |b210| -- |uhd source|

When Rx B210 use only one channel there is no frequency difference between transitted and receivied sine (only constant phase diference).

When RX B210 use 2 channel, the two RX sines are coherent, but there is small frequency difference between TX sine and Rx sine. The level of difference is dependent from RF working frequency.

Any ideas?